# How does Gradle build android using plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, wrapper

I understand as Gradle is build tool and android provide plugin for android build.

When Gradle meet "apply plugin : 'android'" gradle-0.13.3.jar will be downloaded somewhere. right??

But I can not find android plugin anywhere.

How does Gradle build android using plugin ??

Answer (score 2):

`apply plugin: "xyz"` applies a plugin that's already on the build class path. To get a third-party plugin such as the Android plugin on the build class path, a plugin dependency has to be specified in a `buildscript` block. For details on this, check the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) or the [Android Gradle plugin docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

(Gradle 2.1 introduces a new `plugins` block that allows to apply plugins available from http://plugins.gradle.org/ without specifying a plugin dependency.)